# Cassandra with apache spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cassandra-2.1

I want to do some analytical queries and some range queries as well on the time series data stored in Cassandra. For tgis, I came across Apache Spark which supports all these stuffs. May I know any good tutorial/resources on how can I integrate apache spark with Cassandra and make queries ?

I am well familiar with Java/J2EE, SQL and CQL stuffs but not with scala.will it be good to learn scala for this poc ? I am using Cassandra 2.2.

Comment: Have you tried google? I'm guessing https://academy.datastax.com/demos/getting-started-apache-spark-and-cassandra would be worth reading. As for language, Spark has a Java API, so you do not _need_ to learn Scala for this. That said, I think you will find that most of the Spark community use Scala, and it will thus probably be easier to find tutorials and questions/answers in Scala. Personally, I think you should learn Scala simply because it's an awesome language :)

Answer (score 1):

Before reading theory, spend time in understanding the architecture.

Check good videos in [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=apache+cassandra+spark+tutorial)

Once you understand architecture, get familiar with simple theory at [Tutorials Point Cassandra](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cassandra/index.htm),[Tutorials Point Spark](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_spark/) ,[Apache Spark](http://spark.apache.org/) and [Apache Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/)

Then you can go through [cassandra datastax](http://www.datastax.com/resources/tutorials)  tutorial to learn concepts in depth and proceed with [integration of spark and cassandra](https://academy.datastax.com/demos/getting-started-apache-spark-and-cassandra)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

https://academy.datastax.com/courses/getting-started-apache-spark

You could have googled it.
Anyways the tutorial contains a very good explanation of spark and shows how spark work with cassandra.

Hope you learn what you are looking for. :)

Comment: Well, thank you all for your comments. I was thinking to use spark-cassandra connector(https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/0_quick_start.md) for this. It says that, I need to have spark clsuter. So, when downloading Spark which type I should go for. Here is the link for the download page :http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html.